# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string (Laravel Query Builder)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am querying database from Laravel Query Builder and got this error:
`Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`

The function in which I'm getting error is:

```
final public function getFriendIds(int $user_id): Collection
{
    return DB::table('friends')->select('user_id')->where('friends_id', '=', $user_id)->where('status','=', 'accepted')->union(static function (Builder $query) use ($user_id) {
        $query->select('friends_id')->from('friends')->where('user_id', '=', $user_id)-> where('status', '=', 'accepted');
    })->get();
}
```

The function that's calling it is:

```
    final public function suggestFriends(int $user_id): Collection
    {
        return DB::table('users')->select('id', 'name', 'profile_image', 'city', 'country')->where('id', '!=', $user_id)->whereNotIn('id', $this->getFriendIds($user_id))->get();
    }
```

Where am I making mistake?

Comment: what is the contents of $this->getFriendIds($user_id)

Comment: It is the first function I posted above. It basically returns the ids of all the users that are your friends like this:
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#295 ▼
#items: array:2 [▼
0 => {#304 ▼
+"user_id": 3
}
1 => {#302 ▼
+"user_id": 2}
  ]
}

Comment: is that an array or an stdclass .. ? ;)

Comment: When I dump the results, it is returning the instance of Collection, but I got The error for stdClass

Comment: instead of **$this->getFriendsids()** pass [2,3]

Comment: it works then..

Comment: Ok, I found the solution, the collection returned has the data in array, but each index in that array is an object. That's why it is throwing the error. Thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: do you want me to post it as an answer ?